# Java 8 shows this error. Local variable itemList defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am writing the code using java 8 but I iterate a `List` and then find `RestaurantOrderBook` using category type. and put that `List` into a `Map`. it shows this error:

> Local variable **itemList** defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final

```
Query query = new Query();
String categ = category;
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("restaurantId").is(restaurantId));

List<RestaurantOrderBook> itemList = new ArrayList<RestaurantOrderBook>();
itemList = mongoTemplate.find(query, RestaurantOrderBook.class);
System.out.println("size : " + itemList.size());
Map<String , List<RestaurantOrderBook>> map = new HashMap<String , List<RestaurantOrderBook>>();
        Arrays.asList("TakeAway", "Dining").forEach(e ->{

//Following line throws error:              
List<RestaurantOrderBook> list  = itemList.stream().filter(a -> !a.getOrderType().isEmpty() && a.getOrderType().equals(e)).collect(Collectors.toList());
                map.put(e, list);
        });
```

I have an another situation:

```
@Override
    public EventReportRewardsPoints eventReportRewardsPoints(String organizerId) {
        try{
            List<Event> listOfEvents = eventRepo.findByOrganizerId(organizerId);
            EventReportRewardsPoints eventTransReport = new EventReportRewardsPoints();
            Integer soldTics = 0;
            Double totalRevenue = 0d;
            Integer soldToday  = 0;

            Integer findTotalAvailableTics = 0;
            Integer findTotalQtytics = 0;

            for (Event event : listOfEvents) {
                List<EventTicket> eventTicket = eventTicketRepo.findByEventId(event.getId());

                Integer sumOfAvailabletics = eventTicket.stream()
                        .mapToInt(EventTicket::getRemainingTickets).sum();
                findTotalAvailableTics = findTotalAvailableTics + sumOfAvailabletics;

                Integer sumOfQtytics = eventTicket.stream().mapToInt(EventTicket::getQty).sum();
                findTotalQtytics  = findTotalQtytics + sumOfQtytics;

                List<EventTicketBook> listOfEventsTic = eventTicketBookRepository.findByEventId(event.getId());
                for (EventTicketBook eventTicketBook : listOfEventsTic) {
                    Double sumOfSales = eventTicketBook.getTickets().stream().mapToDouble(EventTicket::getPrice).sum();
                    totalRevenue = totalRevenue + sumOfSales;
                    Date now = new Date();
                    System.out.println("create date : " + eventTicketBook.getCreateOn());
                    /*if(now.compareTo(eventTicketBook.getCreateOn()) == 0){
                        Integer sumOfSoldToday = eventTicketBook.getTickets().stream().mapToInt(EventTicket::getQty).sum();
                        soldToday = soldToday + sumOfSoldToday;
                    }*/
                }
            }
            System.out.println("findTotalQtytics : " + findTotalQtytics);
            System.out.println("findTotalAvailableTics : " + findTotalAvailableTics);
            soldTics = findTotalQtytics - findTotalAvailableTics;
            eventTransReport.setTotalRevenue(totalRevenue);
            eventTransReport.setSoldToday(soldToday);
            eventTransReport.setTicketsSold(soldTics);
            return eventTransReport;
        }catch(Exception e ){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

How do i achive this using lamda expression.??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: Local variable mi defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33799800/java-local-variable-mi-defined-in-an-enclosing-scope-must-be-final-or-effective)

Comment: i have read the posts in stackover flow but i could not understand it. please explain me in a easy way.

Comment: I am quite curious, why this is downvoted, because it is in Java 8 lambda / streams area a common problem. Or is it because of duplication?

Comment: @Navaneethan Arun Please ask a new question instead of enhancing the original question with a second one

Comment: @Stefan Zobel i would like to convert my second situation as lamda. please convert the code or give me your idea to do it myself. thanks for golden time spending for me.

Comment: @Navaneethan Arun It's not clear to me what you want to achieve. Please ask a new question and try to expose as clearly as possible what your problem is.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are using **itemList** within a lambda expression. Therefore it has to be final.

Java 8 introduces the new concept of **effectivly final**, which means, the compiler checks, if a used variable is final in usage and does not force the developer to explicitly declare it as final.

So if you change your code to

```
final List<RestaurantOrderBook> itemList = new ArrayList<RestaurantOrderBook>();
```

you will see, that the compiler gives you an error at:

```
itemList = mongoTemplate.find(query, RestaurantOrderBook.class);
```

because you are reasigning **itemList**. That is why **itemList** is not effectivly final as well. If you squash these two lines to

```
List<RestaurantOrderBook> itemList = mongoTemplate.find(query, RestaurantOrderBook.class);
```

it should work.

Comment: can i add some more records in the future ? because it is final.

Comment: Yes. final means only, you cannot set itemList to another List instance, but means not that your List instance in itself is read only.

Comment: hello @wumpz i have put another situation. how do i write the code as lamda.? when i write it it gives the same error. "Local variable itemList defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final"

Comment: Where do you use your lambda expression within the second example? I can only see method references.

Comment: i would like to convert my second situation as lamda. please convert the code or give me your idea to do it myself. thanks for golden time spending for me.

Comment: I am not sure what you are intend to do. Do you want to replace your for loops with forEach?

Comment: you are right. to FOR EACH loop. how to do tell me please

Comment: First of all you should ask yourself: Why? There should be the same performance for both for and foreach.

Answer (score 0):

Declare your variable itemList final:

```
final List<RestaurantOrderBook> itemList = mongoTemplate.find(query, RestaurantOrderBook.class);
```

Comment: is that good way to declare as final? 
maybe i will add some record in future in the list. what will  i do?

Comment: That is not necessary. Effectivly final means, the compiler checks the usage. Therefore this answer does only provide the error message at the right place.

Comment: With the final keyword you can still add items to the list, but you can't assign a different list to the variable itemList.

Comment: That is correct, but it is not necessary for the usage within a lambda expression, because the compiler will check it for you (effectivly final).

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the accepted answer by ***wumpz***, the reason is that the variable being used has to be final or effectively final.

I would like to add the **reason** as to **why it is so**:

When we write a Lambda expression, we are effectively authoring an anonymous inner class. For Ex:

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface MyInterface{
    public void print();
}
```

Used in our code as:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 6;  

        new MyInterface() {             
            @Override
            public void print() {                
                System.out.println(++i); // Remove ++ to resolve error
            }
        }.print();
    }
```