# Local variable defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final

Tags: java

I'm trying to print out the percentage of `x/mol`, but I cannot seem to get it to work.  I am getting a this error: `Local variable x defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final`

It says this happens at line 22, and there is no easy fix for it.  What is java's scope, and how can I add x to the scope so that my timer can read it.

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class mol {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String writable = "";
        BigInteger x = new BigInteger("0");
        BigInteger mol = new BigInteger("602214179000000000000000");
        File file = new File("molA.txt");
        BufferedWriter bw = null;
        FileWriter fw = null;
        Timer t;
        t = new Timer(10000, new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println(x.divide(mol) + "%");
                System.out.println(x);
            }
        });

        System.out.println("Starting...");
        t.start();


        do {
             writable += "a";
            x = x.add(new BigInteger("1"));
        } while (x.compareTo(mol) < 0);

        try {

            fw = new FileWriter(file);
            bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            bw.write(writable);

            System.out.println("Done");

        } catch (IOException e) {

            System.out.println(e);

        } finally {

            try {

                if (bw != null)
                    bw.close();

                if (fw != null)
                    fw.close();

            } catch (IOException ex) {

                System.out.println(ex);

            }
        }
        t.stop();
        System.out.println("Finished!");

    }
}
```

Comment: "_It says this happens at line 22_" We don't have line numbers so please indicate what line of code that is.

Comment: @takendarkk the errors comes from the first two lines with `System.out.println`

Comment: So much for getting the OP to actually update their question. I can copy/paste to notepad++ if I really actually needed to know what the line numbers are.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: Local variable mi defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33799800/java-local-variable-mi-defined-in-an-enclosing-scope-must-be-final-or-effective)

Comment: @Harald it's not a duplicate since in this case the OP **wants* to be able to re-assign `x` so it cannot be declared `final`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't use a local variable inside a nested class since the JVM requires it to be `final` or at least "effectively final" (which means the value of `x` cannot be modified down the road).

You can by-pass it by declaring `x` outside of main as a static variable:

```
static volatile BigInteger x = new BigInteger("0");
public static void main(String[] args) {
....
```

Pay attention that it is also declared to be `volatile` since the main thread modified it and you want the Timer to see the updated value of `x` (if you don't declare it volatile the Timer might see stale values).

Comment: Of course, this becomes a problem if there are multiple instances of `mol`. I prefer to make it an instance variable and instantiate a `mol` in `main`, pulling the guts of main into another method.

Comment: @StephenP that would indeed be a good workaround if multiple instances of `mol` are required and also a good practice in general (not to do everything inside main).

Answer (score 2):

Create a class to hold the BigDecimals

```
public class MyContainer {
    private BigDecimal x = null;

    public MyContainer(BigDecimal x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public BigDecimal getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(BigDecimal x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
}
```

Then in your code on line 14 or so.

```
final MyContainer myContainer = new MyContainer(new BigDecimal(0));
```

Then in your timer,

```
System.out.println(myContainer.getX().divide(mol) + "%");
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to use a method's local variable inside a nested class, the variable must either be either `final` or "effectively final", where the latter means that the compiler can prove that that the variable's value will not change during the entire execution of the method.  If that condition were not satisfied then the semantics of the nested class's usage of the variable would be unclear -- which of the multiple values of the variable would be used, at which point?

There are several ways you could address the problem:

1. For your particular purpose, it looks like you should declare `x` as a class variable instead of a local variable.  (It cannot be an instance variable because you are accessing it from static context.)  You do, however, have the alternative to
2. make `x` final or effectively final.  For example, copy the reference to `x` to a `final` variable, and make your `ActionListener` access that copy instead of accessing `x`.
3. Or you could create and instantiate a named `ActionListener` implementation class, nested or top-level, with a constructor to which you could pass `x`.  That implementation can then use the reference it is initialized with to access the object to which `x` refers, but since `BigInteger`s are immutable, it could not modify that object.

Comment: Solutions #2 and #3 are not good in this case since the OP clearly wants to be able to re-assign `x` and have the `Timer` be aware of the new value.

Comment: Well yes, @alfasin, that's why I say that #1 is what it appears the OP should do.  The other alternatives are intended mainly to provide a better view of the *general* problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use the delegate pattern

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.math.BigInteger;

import javax.swing.Timer;

public class BigDecimalTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringBuffer writable = new StringBuffer;
        final MyBigInteger x = new MyBigInteger("0");
        BigInteger mol = new BigInteger("602214179000000000000000");
        Timer t;
        t = new Timer(10000, new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println(x.divide(mol) + "%");
                System.out.println(x);
            }
        });

        System.out.println("Starting...");
        t.start();

        do {
             writable.append("a");
             x.add(new BigInteger("1"));
        } while (x.compareTo(mol) < 0);

        File file = new File("molA.txt");
        try (
                FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
                ) {
            bw.write(writable.toString());
            System.out.println("Done");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        t.stop();
        System.out.println("Finished!");
    }
}


import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Random;

public class MyBigInteger extends BigInteger {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private BigInteger delegate = null;

    public MyBigInteger(byte[] arg0) {
        super(arg0);
        delegate = new BigInteger(arg0);
    }

    public MyBigInteger(String arg0) {
        super(arg0);
        delegate = new BigInteger(arg0);
    }

    public MyBigInteger(int arg0, byte[] arg1) {
        super(arg0, arg1);
        delegate = new BigInteger(arg0, arg1);
    }

    public MyBigInteger(String arg0, int arg1) {
        super(arg0, arg1);
        delegate = new BigInteger(arg0, arg1);
    }

    public MyBigInteger(int arg0, Random arg1) {
        super(arg0, arg1);
        delegate = new BigInteger(arg0, arg1);
    }

    public MyBigInteger(int bitLength, int certainty, Random rnd) {
        super(bitLength, certainty, rnd);
        delegate = new BigInteger(bitLength, certainty, rnd);
    }

    @Override
    public MyBigInteger divide(BigInteger divisor) {
        delegate = delegate.divide(divisor);
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public MyBigInteger add(BigInteger addition) {
        delegate = delegate.add(addition);
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return delegate.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(BigInteger compare) {
        return delegate.compareTo(compare);
    }
}
```

I am concerned that you are attempting to write 510Zb (510 Zetta Bytes) to a file, or even try to create a String that long. I would guess your system will crash because you don't have enough memory to hold the String, and you don't have enough disk space for a swap file, or to write the molA.txt file. If it does work, it'll probably take a long time to run.