# Setting mouse event to multiple labels in a loop

Tags: java, javafx

I have a grid of 100 javafx labels in a program using a gui I made in scenebuilder. I'm trying to set it up so whenever you click on a label, the label turns the color green.

I have the labels in a two dimensional array list. I'm using a nested for loop to traverse the list, and then then using the setOnMouseClicked function to set the mouse event, instead of creating a function for all 100 labels.

However, I cannot access the for loop control variables in the EventHandler method.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            {
                labels.get(i).get(j).setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){
                    
                    @Override
                    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                        
                        labels.get(i).get(j).setTextFill(Color.GREEN);
                        
                    }
                    
                });
            }
        }
```

`Local variable i defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final`

The error only pops up for 'i' in ecllipse but I assume its affecting both.

What is a different way around this problem? I don't have to use a loop to set the mouse events up, that was just my attempt at solving the problem of setting up 100 labels to be clicked on.

Comment: @jewelsea You are incorrect with the variables needing to be final, as this will not work. Each listener class is created within the double loop. Once the loops have completed the variables are gone and no longer accessible. The answer is to pass in the two variables into the listener which are stored as  class fields, then use those when the listener triggers. I have an answer with this, however you managed to close the question before I could post it :-(

Comment: I'm not wrong ;-). I'll reopen the question so that a specific answer can be posted.

Answer (score 2):

This is really a duplicate of:

- [Java: Local variable mi defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33799800/java-local-variable-mi-defined-in-an-enclosing-scope-must-be-final-or-effective)

but reopened on request so that specific solutions to your question can be posted.

An explanation of what is going on is at:

- [Baeldung: Why Do Local Variables Used in Lambdas Have to Be Final or Effectively Final?](https://www.baeldung.com/java-lambda-effectively-final-local-variables)

The fix is simple, just define and use local final constants:

```
List<List<Label>> labels = new ArrayList<>(new ArrayList<>());

// (omitted) additional initialization of the label instances as needed . . .

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    final int row = i;
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        final int col = j;
        labels.get(row).get(col).setOnMouseClicked(event ->
            labels.get(row).get(col).setTextFill(GREEN)
        );
    }
}
```

This isn't the only way to solve the issue, there are other solutions if you search for them.  But it is, as far as I can tell, the most direct answer to the question.

**Working Example**

This example adds some styling and initialization of the labels as well as some interactive functionality to demonstrate what is going on.  Because of this, the example is slightly more complicated than the minimum required to solve the problem (which is illustrated in the above code snippet already).

[image]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.TilePane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static javafx.scene.paint.Color.GREEN;

public class MultiLabelApplication extends Application {
    private static final int N_ROWS = 5;
    private static final int N_COLS = 5;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Label lastClicked = new Label("No Selection");
        lastClicked.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        TilePane grid = new TilePane(5, 5);
        grid.setPrefRows(N_ROWS);
        grid.setPrefColumns(N_COLS);
        grid.setMinSize(TilePane.USE_PREF_SIZE, TilePane.USE_PREF_SIZE);
        grid.setMaxSize(TilePane.USE_PREF_SIZE, TilePane.USE_PREF_SIZE);

        List<List<Label>> labels = new ArrayList<>(new ArrayList<>());
        for (int i = 0; i < N_ROWS; i++) {
            final int row = i;

            labels.add(new ArrayList<>());

            for (int j = 0; j < N_COLS; j++) {
                final int col = j;

                final Label label = new Label(row + "," + col);
                label.setPadding(new Insets(10));
                label.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
                    label.setTextFill(GREEN);
                    lastClicked.setText(
                        "Last clicked row: " + row + ", col: " + col
                    );
                });

                labels.get(row).add(label);
                grid.getChildren().add(label);
            }
        }

        VBox layout = new VBox(10, lastClicked, grid);
        layout.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        Scene scene = new Scene(layout);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(CSS);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setResizable(false);

        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

    public static final String CSS = "data:text/css," + // language=CSS
            """
            .root {
                -fx-font-size: 16px;
                -fx-background-color: cornsilk;
            }
            
            .label {
                -fx-background-color: palegreen; 
                -fx-text-fill: darkgreen;
            }
            
            TilePane .label {
                -fx-background-color: lightblue; 
                -fx-text-fill: navy;
            }
            """;
}
```

Comment: nit-pick: the final keyword isn't needed :) It's enough to have a new local field `int row = i;`

Answer (score 1):

Using @jewelsea's answer, I want to show you another way to do this without using `final`. I don't know if there are any drawbacks or pitfalls.

You can use the `MouseEvent` to determine which node was pressed by calling `event.getSource()`. See the altered code below.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.TilePane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static javafx.scene.paint.Color.GREEN;

public class App extends Application {
    private static final int N_ROWS = 5;
    private static final int N_COLS = 5;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Label lastClicked = new Label("No Selection");
        lastClicked.setStyle("-fx-background-color: palegreen; -fx-text-fill: darkgreen; -fx-font-size: 16px;");
        lastClicked.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        TilePane grid = new TilePane(5, 5);
        grid.setPrefRows(N_ROWS);
        grid.setPrefColumns(N_COLS);
        grid.setMinSize(TilePane.USE_PREF_SIZE, TilePane.USE_PREF_SIZE);
        grid.setMaxSize(TilePane.USE_PREF_SIZE, TilePane.USE_PREF_SIZE);
        grid.setStyle("-fx-background-color: cornsilk;");

        List<List<Label>> labels = new ArrayList<>(new ArrayList<>());
        for (int row = 0; row < N_ROWS; row++) {
            labels.add(new ArrayList<>());

            for (int col = 0; col < N_COLS; col++) {
                Label label = new Label(row + "," + col);
                label.setPadding(new Insets(10));
                label.setStyle("-fx-background-color: lightblue; -fx-text-fill: navy; -fx-font-size: 16px;");
                label.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
                    Label tempLabel = ((Label)event.getSource());
                    tempLabel.setTextFill(GREEN);
                    lastClicked.setText("Last clicked row: " + tempLabel.getText());
                });

                labels.get(row).add(label);
                grid.getChildren().add(label);
            }
        }

        VBox layout = new VBox(10, lastClicked, grid);
        layout.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        stage.setScene(new Scene(layout));
        stage.setResizable(false);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: In your solution it would be better to create handler only once before loop:)

Comment: @Alex, that's a matter of opinion. I think this is easier to follow, and the amount of code is pretty much the same. I could see the argument if there was a ton of code in the hander.

Comment: of course. But in this case you'll have only one instance of handler