# Mutiny pipeline statistics

Tags: java, reactive-programming, mutiny

Say I have any `Multi` pipeline

```
Multi<Integer> multi = Multi.createFrom().emitter(em -> {
    Thread.sleep(1);
    em.emit(1);

    Thread.sleep(1);
    em.emit(2);

    Thread.sleep(1);
    em.emit(3);

    em.complete();
});
multi
    .onItem().invoke(i -> { System.out.println(i); } )
    .subscribe();
```

Say that, at the end, after all records, you want to log also some "statistics" on the pipeline: how many records floated, how much time the process took.

I tried the following, naive, approach:

```
Date start, end;
int numItems = 0;
Multi<Integer> multi = Multi.createFrom().emitter(em -> {
    start = new Date();
    Thread.sleep(1);
    em.emit(1);
    ++numItems;

    Thread.sleep(1);
    em.emit(2);
    ++numItems;

    Thread.sleep(1);
    em.emit(3);
    ++numItems;

    em.complete();
});
multi.onCompletion()
        .invoke(() -> {
            end = new Date();
            System.out.println("END items=" + numItems+ " time elapsed "+ (end.getTime() - start.getTime()) + "ms");
        })
    .onItem().invoke(i -> { System.out.println(i); } )
    .subscribe();
```

However this cannot even compile because "*Local variables defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively*".

What is the correct approach to this?

**EDIT**

This is **not** a duplicate of [Java: Local variable mi defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33799800).

I am not (only) interested in the problem of *final local variables*. I would like to know if there is some other mutiny-specific approach to this situation.